# Localizing Emacs shortcuts

Tags: emacs

I recently started using Emacs for editing. When I edit english-language files (like program sources) - everything is fine. But when I start editing in my native language, I run into problems.

For example, normally we have C-e shortcut to go to the end of the line. But when I switch my native keyboard layout, emacs starts to complain that "C-у is not defined".

Is there a way to instruct it to map native characters to ascii characters, when entering commands?

Comment: Did you try using Emacs inbuilt input system. C-\

Comment: @kindahero - wow, that works! If you format your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs has its own [input](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Input-Methods.html) system. Emacs 24 goes beyond by supporting right to left languages(both displaying and input). it can be accessed by pressing <kbd>C-\</kbd>